# Connecting ignite server that runs as docker container inside kubernetes from outside client process

Tags: kubernetes, ignite, discovery

I have minikube running kubernetes inside a virtual box.
one of the docker container it runs is an ignite server.
during my development I try to access the ignite server from outside java client but the discovery fails with all configurations I tried.
is it possible at all? 
If yes can someone give an example?

Comment: I am not an expert in kubernetes, but it seems you need to properly configure port-forwarding virtualbox <--> kubernetes <--> docker <--> ignite node.
perhaps, the following links will be helpful:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/docker-deployment

Comment: Already tried both. didn't help

Answer (score 0):

To enable Apache Ignite nodes auto-discovery in Kubernetes, you need to enable `TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder` in `IgniteConfiguration`. Read more about this on https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/kubernetes-deployment. Your Kubernetes service definitions should have the container exposed port specified, then minikube should give you service URL after successful deployment.